# Scipy CSR sparse matrix is actually COO?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy

I've been recently dealing with sparse matrices. My aim is to somehow convert an adjacency list for a graph into the CSR format, defined here: http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/CSR.png.

One possible option I see, is that I simply first construct a NumPy matrix and convert it using `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`. The problem is, that the CSR in SciPy is somewhat different to the one discussed in the link. My question is, is this just a discrepancy, and I need to write my own parser, or can SciPy in fact convert into CSR defined in the link.

A bit more about the problem, let's say I have a matrix:

```
matrix([[1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1]])
```

CSR format for this consists of two arrays, Column(C) and row(R). And i strive for looks like:

```
C: [0,1,2,0,2]

R: [0,2,3,5]
```

SciPy returns the:

```
  (0, 0)    1
  (0, 1)    1
  (1, 2)    1
  (2, 0)    1
  (2, 2)    1
```

where second column is the same as my C, yet this is to my understanding the COO format, not the CSR. (this was done using `csr_matrix(adjacency_matrix)` function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference in what is stored internally and what you see when you simply print the matrix via `print(A)` (where `A` is a `csr_matrix`).

In the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) the attributes are listed. Among others there are the following three attributes:

> data      CSR format data array of the matrix
>   indices   CSR format index array of the matrix
>   indptr    CSR format index pointer array of the matrix

You can access (and manipulate) them through `A.data`, `A.indices` and `A.indptr`.

Bottom line: The CSR format in scipy is a "real" CSR format and you do not need to write your own parser (as long as you don't care about the in your case unnecessary `data` array).
Also note: A matrix in [CSR format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_.28CSR.2C_CRS_or_Yale_format.29) is always represented by three arrays, not two.

Comment: Thanks! This was the missing information i did not have. I realize there is a three array representation, but the pointer part will be written separately.